# How to replace this old backflow preventer with new one

Tags: plumbing, pipe, valve, backflow-preventer

I want to replace this old broken Pressure Vacuum Breaker Valve with new one. Problem is that all the new ones at HomeDepot and Lowes have outflow on the left side. Can someone show me with a sketch on how to line up the outflow pipes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are the valves on the new one integral to the backflow preventer, or are they screwed on?  Because they look screwed on, and in that case, you could just flip the whole thing around and then turn the valves to face you.

Comment: Tighten the valves normally if loosened they may leak.+

Comment: If you are using a municipal water supply , you may technically need an approved valve and an inspection after installation.

Answer (score 0):

Nate S wrote "Are the valves on the new one integral to the backflow preventer, or are they screwed on? Because they look screwed on, and in that case, you could just flip the whole thing around and then turn the valves to face you."

Yes, valves are screwed on. So I can just turn them to face me. I think they did the same thing on the existing backflow. [Nate S](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/91556/nate-s) - thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks for answering your question. Please be sure to click the check mark so others know that this has a confirmed, working solution!